# Itinerary details for schengen visa - should I mention every individual place for sightseeing?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, spain, itineraries

I am creating an itinerary for a Spanish Schengen visa. I am planning to include the dates of travel, the names of the hostels that have been booked for particular dates(number of days of booking included) and dates of internal travel.

Should I **mention every individual place that I will go to for sightseeing every day**?
Or just the dates of travel, place of stay and information about internal travel is enough ?